# How to have a webpage File Save As filename different from the page URL?

Tags: users, files, 7

For example - see this BBC News Page: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-16578905

Now Save the page as a web page - notice how the actual filename of the file saved ( BBC News - Golden Globes  Ricky Gervais 'subdued', say critics.htm ) is different from the last URL fragment ( "entertainment-arts-16578905" ).

Drupal has great clean meaningful URL rewriting, I would like to use this as much as possible, so, for me, another example might be e.g. http://example.com/blog/entry-2012-01-17 and the filename could be "mysite.com - blog entry on 2012-01-17.html"

I'm sure that there might be a meta or otherwise setting in the HTML to achieve this, but how can Drupal insert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually chrome browser (and some others) doing this based on the page title. For example firefox will actually prefer to save as the last part of the url instead. Make sure to use http://drupal.org/project/page_title module and that should give you what you are looking for. Not sure if there is a way to force it on firefox too.

Comment: +1 thanks @7wonders - I will check out page_title and report back and hopefully declare your answer as accepted.

Comment: I'll accept for now and write back with findings once I've tried the module.